# Study the injectivity and surjectivity of the function $D:\mathbb{R}_n[x]->\mathbb{R}_{n-1}[x], D(f) = f'$

Tags: linear-algebra

As the title says, I want to study the injectivity and surjectivity of the function:

$D:\mathbb{R}_n[x]->\mathbb{R}_{n-1}[x], D(f) = f'$

I think it is pretty straight forward that the function is not injective because if we take let's say $f_1=1$ and $f_2=2$ and both of them have $f_1'=f_2'=0$.

Now, the problem is how do I study the surjectivity? I was thinking about finding if $Im\ f=\{g\in \mathbb{R}_{n-1}[x]\ |\ \exists f so\  that\ D(f) = g\}$ is exactly $\mathbb{R}_{n-1}[x]$.

Now if we take $B_1 = \{1,x,x^2,...,x^n\}$ and $B_2 = \{1,x,x^2,...,x^{n-1}\}$ and we do

$D(1) = 0$

$D(x) = 1$

...

$D(x^n) = nx^{n-1}$

we can write a matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & ... & 0\\ 
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & n
\end{pmatrix}$

and we can say that $Im\ f = Col(A) = span (0 , 1, 2,..., n)$

but I do not really know if it is right what I did so far and what to do next. Can you give me any help? Do you think there is an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For surjectivity (ontoness) it is enough to show that we can produce any basis vector $\{1,x, \ldots ,x^{n-1}\}$. With that in mind, it is easy to see that
$$D\left(\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}\right)=x^{k}.$$
Thus every polynomial in the basis given above can be mapped.

So if we have $f(x) \in \Bbb{R}_{n-1}[x]$ given by $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kx^{k}$, then let
$$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_k}{k+1}x^{k+1} \in \Bbb{R}_n[x].$$
Note that
$$D(g(x))=f(x).$$
So we can map to any $f(x) \in \Bbb{R}_{n-1}[x]$

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

1. What is the derivative of the integral of $f$?
2. If $f\in\mathbb R_{n-1}[x]$, then the integral of $f$ is an element of $\mathbb R_n[x]$.

Comment: Well, the derivate of integral of $f$ is $f$. Can you explain a little more, please?$

Comment: @Ghost I added point $2$ of my hints.

Comment: So, you want to tell me to think backwards. Like, any $f$ we take that belongs to $\mathbb{R}_{n-1}[x]$ and we integrate it we get a $g$ that belongs to $\mathbb{R}_{n}[x]$ and the derivative of the $g$ is exactly $f$.

Comment: @Ghost I wouldn't call that thinking "backwards". In general, you can prove that a function $f:A\to B$ is surjective by proving that, for every element $b\in B$, there exists some element $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. Now apply that to your problem.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your answer. I just did not think about the integration. I will accept the other answer since it's a little bit more detailed if you don't mind. Both are literally saying the same thing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can just note that the nullity of $D$ is $1$; only constants belong to the null space of $D$. By the rank-nullity theorem, $\text{rank}(D)=\dim(\Bbb R_n[x])-\dim(\ker(D))=n+1-1=n=\dim(\Bbb R_{n-1}[x])$, which means $\text{Im}(D)=R_{n-1}[x]$.

Comment: Oh, that is also a nice way to do it. Thanks for the tip!